# How do I know which UV channel I'm viewing for each selected object(s)

Tags: python, uv, uv-image-editor

It seems I can only select the channel of my active object(s) and there doesn't seem to be anything to show that when I go to the second channel of one of my object's UVs. The other objects show their 2nd channel if they have one. I am open to using any add-ons or scripts that can function as a workaround if selecting the second channel in every mesh isn't an option natively.

Answer (score 1):

I made a script that prints the name of all selected objects alongside the name of those selected objects active UV.

```py
import bpy

for o in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    if o.type == "MESH":
        for u in o.data.uv_layers:
            if u.active:
                print(o.name + " | " + u.name)
```

Output should look something similar to this:

```
Cube | UVMap.001
Sphere | UVMap
```